# How to manage and configure multiple gitlab repositories as code

Tags: gitlab

I have a Gitlab group with subgroups and lots of projects per subgroup.

I am looking for a way to manage all those repos and their settings (members, branch protection rules, push rules etc).
Lots of my repos need to share the same configuration, but not all.

For example: I would like to be able to apply new settings to existing repos.
I would also like to be able to create new repos based on a template.
All this needs to be done 'as code' and versionned.

I have seen existing Terraform and Ansible providers to interact with Gitlab.
Have any of you tried one of these approaches ?
Are there any other tools you could recommended for the job ?

Comment: What do you mean by "configuration"? Project settings in GitLab?

Comment: Yes, exactly ! Project settings, branch protection, project members etc...
I will edit the question to make it clear.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [GitLab Project Configurator](https://gitlab.com/grouperenault/gitlab-project-configurator) tool. It has several high-level configurable [nodes](https://grouperenault.gitlab.io/gitlab-project-configurator/docs/config_files.html#high-level-nodes) with many parameters in each:

- variable_profiles
- member_profiles
- label_profiles
- projects_rules
- projects_configuration
- groups_rules
- groups_configuration